Determine Rotation Angles for Overlaying Regular Polygons on a Sphere
On a sphere of radius $R$, suppose I have regular polygons $P$ and $P'$ with vertices $(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n)$ and $(v_1', v_2', \dots, v_n')$ with the polygons positioned so their centroids are on the sphere and the polygons are tangent to the sphere.  $P$ and $P'$ have the same number of vertices and the same size.
There appear to be three extrinsic rotations, $\theta_x$, $\theta_y$, and $\theta_z$, applied in that order (i.e. rotate on the $X$-axis by $\theta_x$, then rotate on the $Y$-axis by $\theta_y$, then rotate on the $Z$-axis by $\theta_z$) that will overlay $P$ on top of $P'$.  How do I determine these angles?
Example: On a sphere of radius 50 ($R = 50$), polygon $P$ is defined by the four vertices $(50, -10, -10)$, $(50, -10, 10)$, $(50, 10, 10)$, and $(50, 10, -10)$, and $P'$ by $(50.31, 11.95, 5.06)$, $(41.69, 28.81, 11.48)$, $(37.99, 20.19, 29.14)$, and $(46.61, 3.33, 22.72)$.  Their centroids are $(50, 0, 0)$ and $(44.15, 16.07, 17.10)$.  It looks like this...

($P$ is blue, $P'$ is red.  Note that $P$ and $P'$ are the same size and have the same number of vertices, with their centroids on the sphere, and with the polygons tangent to the sphere.)
The rotations to overlay $P$ on $P'$ are: $\theta_x = 20$, $\theta_y = -20$, and $\theta_z = 20$.  The question is how to determine the angles.
Using the recipe provided by @Hosam in the answer below, I've developed the following implementation in OpenSCAD.  *** WARNING *** The $atan2$ function I'm using has the signature $atan2(y, x)$ but the signature of the one @Hosan uses has the signature $atan2(x, y)$.
P1 = [
  [50, -10, -10], 
  [50, -10, 10], 
  [50, 10, 10], 
  [50, 10, -10]
];

P2 = [
  [50.3146, 11.9527,  5.0568], 
  [46.6139,  3.3264, 22.7173],
  [41.6883, 28.8130, 11.4847],
  [37.9876, 20.1867, 29.1452] 
];

O1 = aavg(P1); // centroid of first polygon
O2 = aavg(P2); // centroid of second polygon
echo("O1=", O1, "O2=", O2);

zhat1 = O1 / norm(O1);
zhat2 = O2 / norm(O2);
xhat1 = (P1[1] - P1[0]) / norm(P1[1] - P1[0]);
xhat2 = (P2[1] - P2[0]) / norm(P2[1] - P2[0]);
yhat1 = cross(zhat1, xhat1);
yhat2 = cross(zhat2, xhat2);
echo("xhat1=", xhat1, "yhat1=", yhat1, "zhat1=", zhat1);
echo("xhat2=", xhat2, "yhat2=", yhat2, "zhat2=", zhat2);

R1 = [
  [ xhat1[0], yhat1[0], zhat1[0] ],
  [ xhat1[1], yhat1[1], zhat1[1] ],
  [ xhat1[2], yhat1[2], zhat1[2] ]
];
R2 = [
  [ xhat2[0], yhat2[0], zhat2[0] ],
  [ xhat2[1], yhat2[1], zhat2[1] ],
  [ xhat2[2], yhat2[2], zhat2[2] ]
];
R1T = [
  [ xhat1[0], xhat1[1], xhat1[2] ],
  [ yhat1[0], yhat1[1], yhat1[2] ],
  [ zhat1[0], zhat1[1], zhat1[2] ]
];  
R = R2 * R1T;
echo("R1=", R1);
echo("R2=", R2);
echo("R1T=", R1T);
echo("R=", R);

thetaY = asin(-R[2][0]);
c2 = cos(thetaY);
thetaZ = atan2(R[1][0] / c2, R[0][0] / c2);
thetaX = atan2(R[2][1] / c2, R[2][2] / c2);
echo(thetaX, thetaY, thetaZ);

